# ChakraUI fill images in grid

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, chakra-ui

I am creating a Grid of images using Chakra:

```
<Grid
  templateRows='repeat(3, 1fr)'
  templateColumns='repeat(2, 1fr)'
  gap={4}
>
  <GridItem rowSpan={3} >
     <img src="link" style={{width: '100%', height: '100%', objectFit: 'cover'}}/>
  </GridItem>
  <GridItem>
     <img src="link2" style={{width: '100%', height: '100%', objectFit: 'cover'}}/>
  </GridItem>
  <GridItem>
     <img src="link3" style={{width: '100%', height: '100%', objectFit: 'cover'}}/>
  </GridItem>
  <GridItem>
     <img src="link4" style={{width: '100%', height: '100%', objectFit: 'cover'}}/>
  </GridItem>
</Grid>
```

I want the images to auto resize inside their grid space. How can I achieve this?